# Facing issue while adding json key value pair to existing json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, javascript-objects

I am having `JSON` object

```
var jsonData={
  "key1":val1,
  "key2":val2
}
```

I am having array

```
var columns=[100,101,102,103];
var resultarray=[{C_100:1,C_101:2,102:3,C_103:4},{C_100:5,C_101:6,C_102:7,C_103:8};
```

I am looping through result array to get create json object matching the values of columns

```
for(let i=0;i<resultarray.length; i++)
{
  var finalRes=resultarray[i];      
  for (let column = 0; column < columns.length; column++) {                            
    dataVal = finalRes["C_"+columns[column]];                          
    jsonData[columns[column]] = dataVal;                                
  }    
}
```

I want to add json key value pairs in the lopp to existing json object already created.

I am getting jsonObject output as

```
var jsonData=
{
  100:1,
  101:2,
  102:3,
  key1:val1,
  key2:val2,
}
```

Which will not work for my scenario

I am expecting json object as

```
var jsonData=
{    
  key1:val1,
  key2:val2,
  100:1,
  101:2,
  102:3,
}
```

Please let me know how to push items to existing json object which should append at the end;

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does JavaScript guarantee object property order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order)

Comment: btw, you can not increment an array.

Comment: off topic: "json" is a string - you have a javascript object

Comment: [$.extend](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/)

Comment: `resultarray++` looks very odd, should be `i++`

Answer (score 0):

I tried this way and it worked.
I have appended c_ for each column and evrything is string it got appeneded correctly in order.

```
var columns=[C_100,C_101,C_102,C_103];

for(let i=0;i<resultarray.length; i++)
{
  var finalRes=resultarray[i];      
  for (let column = 0; column < columns.length; column++) {                            
    dataVal = finalRes[columns[column]];                          
    jsonData[""+columns[column]""] = dataVal;                                
  }    
}
```

Now i got out put of JsonData as

```
var jsonData=
{    
  key1:val1,
  key2:val2,
  C_100:1,
  C_101:2,
  C_102:3,
  C_103:4
}
```

No i have to work around to remove "C_" from key